# customizing initWithFrame for UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to decide on the best way to customize an initializer for UIView so a value can be passed into the initializer and it is immediately stored as an iVar in the UIView subclass, as this value is required for the drawing in `drawRect`.

Currently I am using the default `initWithFrame` and the class that creates this UIView then sets its iVar to a value *after* calling `initWithFrame`, and it is in fact working; somehow the `drawRect` is getting this iVar's value even though it is set *after* the UIView is initialized.

So I need either one of two things:

1) Confidence to know this is okay: that I can rely on `drawRect` somehow delaying the drawing for a bit so iVars are set by another object after UIView is initialized. In which case, just **when in the UIView initializing does `drawRect` get called?**

Or,

2) I need to pass value during initialization: is this the best way to create a custom initializer that takes more than `(CGRect)frame` as an argument for `initWithFrame.` Could it be as simple as doing this:

```
 myNewView=[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:myRect andMore:myValue];
```

And then in MyCustomView.m:

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andMore:(int)someValue
  {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
       myIvar=someValue;
       ... //continue as normal
     }
  }
```

Would this code be a good approach? Then I would comfortably know that the value is there before `drawRect` is called.

Comment: Yes, your second approach seems sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) You can rely on `drawRect:`to be called after any `init`. In fact, `drawRect:` will be called when the view drawing and compositing is done, which usually happens as a result of a Core Animation commit (done at the end of the runloop if you modify any CALayer or UIView (which are always backed by a CALayer)).

2.) This approach is better from an architectural point of view. If you consider this variable to be an integral part to the functionality of your class (and the class can't work properly without it), it should definitely be an init parameter. you might also consider throwing an NSInternalInconsistencyException (or any other exception) inside other init-Methods and/or mark them as deprecated (init-Methods of the superclass will still work fine when called with `super initWithFrame:`).

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is ideal when you explicitly create the view programmatically using the designated initializer you have specified. Caveat: This will *not* be the case if the view is constructed via a NIB.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: both of your approaches should work fine.

Longer answer:

1. The `drawRect:` method is called in the runloop so won't be called until you have finished doing all your initialising and then relinquished control back to the runloop.  Certainly if you init the view and then immediately set the property you won't have a problem.
2. Your second approach should work pretty much as is.

I would use the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Martin Ullrich** addressed the issue properly.
But i would like to add something.

If you call `initWithFrame` or `init` on your view.This doesn't make `drawRect` method to be invoked.
When you add that view to the window,and `in the next runLoop it will call this method` , which produces a bitmap to de displayed on screen.